# Rails form validation not show the error messages, taking blank fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
My form::

<h1>New Post</h1>

<%= form_for (@post), url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this post from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>


<p>
<%= f.label :Title%><br>
<%= f.text_field :Title%>
</p>

<p>
<%= f.label :Text%><br>
<%= f.text_area :Text%>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.submit :Save %>
    </p>

    <% end %>
```

:: context ::
It is not showing the error messages. please point out the where i am wrong. I want to add basic validations. i have gone through some tutorials but still stuck into this.. please help me out.

Comment: Do you set your validations in your model?

Comment: Share the model validations and the controller method.

Comment: @Pavan :: Thanks for the prompt reply. No i havent set the validations in the model.. the tutorial i am referring to doesnot have that.. can you please tell me how to do that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **Post model**,Just add these line

```
validates_presence_of :title,text #doesn't allow the blank values
```

If you are also looking for validation of unique values for **title**,add this line also.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :title #doesn't allow duplicate values
```

Also Follow these Guides([Rails 4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)),if you are looking for more validations.

Comment: @user3322822 Pleasure to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
validates :title, uniqueness: {message: "must be uniq"}
```